# Gaelic on Ubuntu Touch (Phone)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, language-support

Does anyone know if the Ubuntu Phone will, at any point in the near future, have the option to select Irish (Gaeilge) as the main language?

I bought it because my first language is Irish, my English is pretty good but it makes me uncomfortable; and I was hoping that, like the Desktop version, Gaeilge would soon be supported.

Comment: This isn't really something that every person is going to know. I would reccomend sending a support request to Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there are very few Irish translations for the phone.

http://projects.davidplanella.org/stats/wily/ga

As long as that's the case, it won't happen, of course. You may want to ask the [Irish translation team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-ie) about the plans with respect to phone translations. Possibly you are interested in joining the team and help out. ;)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Hjalmarsson, that is really helpful information, I would up-vote your answer but I sadly don't have the reputation at this moment and time; I greatly appreciate it sir honestly.